# Is it possible to `Protect` a dynamic programming process?

Tags: function-construction, memoization

I wrote a function using dynamic programming to speed up the evaluation. For safety, I also want to protect this function. Take factorial for example:

```
fac[0] = 1;
fac[n_] := fac[n] = n*fac[n - 1];
Protect@fac;
```

`fac[3]` will return a `Set::write` error and give the right answer 6. Although `Quiet@fac[3]` or `Off[Set::write]` seems to work, the sacrifice is the speed, which can be verified by`?fac`:

> Global`fac
>
> Attributes[fac]={Protected}
>
> fac[0]=1
>
> fac[n_]:=fac[n]=n fac[n-1]

i.e. after the evaluation of `fac[3]`, *Mathematica* does not store the values: fac[1],fac[2],fac[3].(Of course it doesn't, since the fac is protected.)

So what can be done to make `Protect` and dynamic programming process live with each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just unprotect and protect on the first call of the recursion.

To avoid checking in every inner call if it's the first or not, you could implement it in a an extra private symbol, and use the public interface as a non-recursive wrapper.

```
Unprotect[fac]; ClearAll[fac];
Module[{facPvt},

 facPvt[1] = 1;
 facPvt[n_Integer] := facPvt[n] = n facPvt[n - 1];

 fac[n_Integer?Positive] := (
    Unprotect[facPvt]; (Protect[facPvt]; #) &@facPvt[n]);

 Protect[fac, facPvt];
 ]
```

Just don't lock `facPvt`

Comment: +1. I noticed that what you do with a pure function is very similar to what I did with `withCodeAfter`.

Comment: Thanks; However, what's the difference between  `(Unprotect[facPvt]; (Protect[facPvt]; #) &@facPvt[n])` and            `(Unprotect[facPvt]; facPvt[n]);` ?

Comment: @luyuwuli that the latter leaves the symbol unprotected after evaluation. If you don't mind that (I wouldn't, since it's a symbol a common user wouldn't even know), then never protect it in the first place.

Comment: @Rojo I'm not sure I understand it correctly: Because `&` has a very low precedence, in `(Protect[facPvt]; #) &@facPvt[n])` , `facPvt[n]` will be evaluated first, then protect it, last return it. If so, why protect facPvt again at the end of the `Module` ?

Comment: @luyuwuli, this module isn't being used to localize `facPvt` in the sense that `facPvt` isn't destroyed after the `Module` exits. It is used so that `facPvt` is actually some other local weird name, such as `facPvt$34` that hadn't been used so far. When someone does `fac[3]`, that `facPvt$34` has to still exist for the function to work. So, between calls, the user could do `facPvt$34[2]="haha"` and ruin everything if it is not protected.

Comment: @Rojo Did you mean this: If `Protect[facPvt]` is removed in the module, there could be a chance one may evaluate `facPvt$34[2]="haha"` **before** the evaluation of `fac`. Then ruin everything.

Comment: Yes. All subsequent evaluations of `fac` after you evaluate that will be ruined.

Comment: @Rojo Now I understand the subtleties here, thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 8):

In many cases, memoization helps for a given particular computation, and one can (or even has to) then remove the memoized values. For such cases, protection can nicely coexist with the technique which I call "self-blocking". I will illustrate this using the infamous Fibonacci numbers example:

```
Unprotect[fib];
ClearAll[fib];
fib[n_] :=
  Block[{fib},
    fib[0] = fib[1] = 1;
    fib[m_?Positive] := fib[m] = fib[m - 1] + fib[m - 2];
    fib[n]
  ];
Protect @ fib;
```

Now, we can use, for example:

```
fib[100]

(* 573147844013817084101 *)
```

while e.g. the following assignment is not allowed:

```
fib[2] = 1
```

> During evaluation of In[2852]:= Set::write: Tag fib in fib[2] is Protected.

```
(* 1 *)
```

The reason this works is that `Block` removes all global properties of the blocked symbol, including the `Protected` attribute. Note that this technique also guarantees that the memoized values are removed after the function finishes, since they only exist inside a dynamic environment created using `Block`.

In more complex cases, some variations of this approach might work as well.

**EDIT**

To address your question on how to keep the generated definitions, here is another method. First, define this handy macro, which allows us to avoid extra scoping constructs (intermediate variables):

```
ClearAll[withCodeAfter];
SetAttributes[withCodeAfter, HoldRest];
withCodeAfter[before_, after_] := (after; before);
```

Now, here is the method (using the same example as before): before all your usual definitions, insert an extra definition:

```
Unprotect[fib];
ClearAll[fib];

call_fib /; MemberQ[Attributes[fib], Protected] :=     
   withCodeAfter[Unprotect[fib]; call, Protect[fib]]

fib[0] = fib[1] = 1;
fib[n_] := fib[n] = fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2];
Protect[fib];
```

This extra definition allows the function, but only the function, to modify itself during its own execution. So, now:

```
fib[50]

(* 20365011074 *)
```

And you can check that the function remains `Protected`, and the generated definitions are now in the global rule base.

This method is general, so all you have to do is to insert your own symbol in place of `fib`, to construct a relevant extra definition for your problem / function. It is important that it is the very first one you give, so it should go before your "usual" definitions.

Comment: If I am understanding your _" also guarantees that the memoized values are removed after the function finished"_ (which is in line with the `Block[]` docs), a subsequent `fib[100]` will start blank. Is there a way to persist the memoized downvalues *and* have the symbol protected?

Comment: Thanks a lot. While I have another problem: If the values are removed after the function finishes and someone may use the values (or part of it) again and again. The evaluation will have to start over. The memory for time strategy will somewhat fail. So is it possible to implement this: definitions can be changed when the package evaluate (or in the package), but any change of it in the notebook (or by hand) is forbidden?

Comment: @belisarius Yes! What you said is exactly what I want:)

Comment: @belisarius Yes, this is possible, although by using a different method. See my edit.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The edit has the drawback that the attributes are checked in every call, which might be fine if the time taken by each step makes this check negligible. Neat implementation

Comment: @Rojo Thanks. Re: checking - this can be improved with your beloved technique based on guards (Villegas - Gayley method). But I think the check should not take much time, and I wouldn't like to make the code more complex unless there is a good reason. In most cases, memoization wins by changing the complexity of the algorithm, so adding a (fairly small) constant factor should probably be Ok.

Comment: @Leonid thanks, I was just about to ask the same question and I found this. Is it possible to write down one of this call_fib  definitions for all the functions in my package that use memoization, something like: call_memo /; MemberQ[Attributes[{func1, func2, func3}], Protected] :=     
   withCodeAfter[Unprotect[func1,func2,func3]; call, Protect[func1,func2,func3]]

Comment: @Santi This is surely possible. The simplest is to have a list of functions and automate this, like `Scan[Function[sym, Pattern[call,Blank[sym]] /; MemberQ[Attributes[sym], Protected]:= withCodeAfter[Unprotect[sym];call, Protect[sym]]], {func1,func2,func3}]` (untested, but you get the idea).

Comment: @Leonid, thanks that seems to work!