# Garbage collection for lexical closures

Tags: programming, scoping, memory

Mathematica is [known](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221520/85954) not to garbage collect temporary variables in certain cases. I am particularly interested in the very useful programming pattern known as a [lexical closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). A somewhat trivial example is

```
getMultiplier[n_] := Module[{f},
  f[x_] := n*x;
  f
];
```

Defining `M = getMultiplier[4]` returns a function that multiplies by 4, for example `M[5]` will return 20. But if one removes the symbol `M` by calling `Remove[M]` then the temporary variable `f` that it referred to will remain in memory and not be garbage collected. This is also true with `$HistoryLength = 0`.

**Question:** *What workarounds can be used to avoid the memory leak that comes with this programming pattern (lexical closure) in Mathematica?* I include two workarounds, but I hope somebody has a more general and more robust solution.

**Workaround 1:** Avoid generating temporary variables in the first place, using an anonymous function as in

```
getMultiplier[n_] := (n*#&);
```

This workaround has various limitations, for example it prohibits common Mathematica patterns such as memoization `f[x_] := f[x] = n*x`.

**Workaround 2:** Explicitly include a remover function as in

```
getMultiplier[n_] := Module[{f},
  f[x_] := n*x;
  f["remove"] := Remove[f];
  f
];
```

One can call `M = getMultiplier[4]`, use it a bunch of times, then call `M["remove"]` just before calling `Remove[M]`, and no memory leak occurs. This workaround amounts to manual memory management, and is both inconvenient and error-prone in larger programs, say when one closure refers to another closure and so on.

**Edit:** If you are aware of low level commands or settings in the vicinity of the Mathematica garbage collector, that could conceivably help with the issue at hand, please point them out. The [Low-Level System Optimization Guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelSystemOptimization.html) shows that there is a `ClearSystemCache` command for example, which is not directly useful here, but if there was say a similar (perhaps hidden) command `ForceFullGarbageCollection` to force a more extensive garbage collection including variables such as `f` above when unreachable, then please point it out. Perhaps the garbage collector does not do this automatically for performance reasons, but can be encouraged to do it?

Comment: Perhaps there is some hack using `System\`Private\`GetRefCount[f]`? The latter is mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221726/85954). Or perhaps there is some way to tell Mathematica explicitly to tie the fate of `f` (and possibly other symbols) to the fate of `M` somehow, so that removal of one leads to the removal of the other? It would be interesting to understand what makes it difficult or impossible for Mathematica to garbage collect these temporary variables itself.

Comment: Essentially the same question was asked in [this Wolfram community thread](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/83845) several years ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an approach to "automate" the usage of the [`` ExpressionCleanup` ``](https://github.com/jasondbiggs/ExpressionCleanup)  paclet mentioned by @LeonidShifrin. The idea is to return an object from your module that contains two symbols: One for the actual downvalues (`f`), and one purely for keeping track of the reference count (`marker`). It is important that the definition of `f` is of the form `f[_][...]`, so that `f` doesn't actually contain a reference to `marker`.

### Updated version

This variant has been suggested by @LeonidShifrin in the comments (thanks!): If we return `Function[marker;f[##]]`, there's no need for subvalues.

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

<< ExpressionCleanup`

addGCMarker[f_] := Module[{marker},
  AddCleanupFunction[marker, Echo@"Removed!"; Remove@f];
  Function[, marker; f[##], HoldAllComplete]
  ]

getMultiplier[n_] := addGCMarker@Module[{f},
  f[x_] := n*x;
  f
  ]

M = getMultiplier[4]
(* Function[Null, marker$5097; f$5096[##1], {}] *)

M[4]
(* 16 *)

M =.
(* Removed! *)

(*f$xxxx is indeed gone*)
Names["f*"]
(* {"f", "f$"} *)
```

`Function` also has the advantage that it supports attributes (which is impossible with subvalues), so we can support functions with `HoldAll` and similar. To do this, I simply make the returned expression `HoldAllComplete`, so that any argument evaluation happens only once the head is actually `f`. This approach also has the advantage that one can in principle retroactively apply the cleanup code, i.e. you don't need to modify the `Module`, you could just as well do `M = addGCMarker@getMultiplier[4]`.

#### Dependency cleanup - Updated version

@user293787 has also asked in the comments how we can handle helper symbols with their own downvalues: I'll present an updated version of the approach here (based on feedback in the comments), the original one is in the next section.

```
<< ExpressionCleanup`
$HistoryLength = 0;

Attributes[makeGCed] = {HoldFirst};
makeGCed[f_Symbol] /; OwnValues[f] === {} && UpValues[f] === {} :=
 Module[
  {marker, proxy},
  Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[] = 
   Language`ExtendedDefinition[f] /. f -> proxy;
  ClearAll[f];
  Attributes[f] = {Temporary};
  AddCleanupFunction[f, Echo@"symbol removed!"];
  AddCleanupFunction[marker, Echo@"marker removed!"; Remove@proxy];
  f = Function[, marker; proxy[##], HoldAllComplete];
  ]

Attributes[GCBlock] = {HoldFirst};
GCBlock[expr_] :=
 Internal`InheritedBlock[
  {Module},
  Unprotect@Module;
  $active = True;
  Module[vars_, body_] /; $active := Block[
    {$active = False},
    Module[
     vars,
     With[{res = Block[{$active = True}, body]},
      Replace[
       Unevaluated@vars, _[s_Symbol, _] | s_Symbol :> makeGCed@s, 1];
      res
      ]
     ]
    ];
  expr
  ]

createMultiplier[m_] :=
 GCBlock@Module[{f, g}, f[x_] := g[x] m; g[x_] := x^2; f]

M = createMultiplier[3]
(* symbol removed! *)
(* Function[Null, marker$5559; proxy$5559[##1], HoldAllComplete] *)

M =.
(* marker removed! *)
(* symbol removed! *)
(* marker removed! *)

(* symbols are indeed all gone *)
Names["f*" | "g*"]
(* {"f", "f$", "g", "g$"} *)
```

The idea is the following: We create a function `GCBlock` that ensures that any `Module` inside it has the GC-augmentation applied to it. This is done by temporarily overriding `Module` to add the necessary code, which requires some careful enabling/disabling of the custom definition to prevent endless loops while supporting nested `Module` constructs. We then run the code as usual, and remember the result. At the end, we go over the list of variables, and call `makeGCed` on them. `makeGCed` tries to make them garbage-collected if they have no own-values (normal variables are anyway cleaned up automatically). `makeGCed` works by copying all definitions of the symbol onto a proxy symbol, which works the same as in the approach above. We then clear the symbol itself, re-apply the `Temporary` attribute, and set it to the `Function[...]` construct. This retro-actively makes the symbol garbage-collectible. This approach can handle nested `Module` constructs, and should be able to clean up symbols with nested dependencies. It will however fail for circular dependencies (I don't have a good idea at the moment to handle those).

It should be noted to `makeGCed` ignores symbols with ownvalues and upvalues. This is because the `Function[...]` trick doesn't work in those cases. For ownvalues it shouldn't matter so much because there the garbage collection usually works.

#### Dependency cleanup - Original version

Here's the original approach for dependency cleanup: One approach is to simply look at the dependencies of `f`, and remove anything with the same module id. This assumes that all those symbols can be removed at the same time as `f`, but given that `f` is the only thing explicitly escaping from the closure, that seems like a reasonable assumption. Here's the code:

```
addGCMarker[f_] := Module[{marker},
  AddCleanupFunction[marker,
   Echo@"Removed!";
   StringCases[SymbolName@f,
    id : ("$" ~~ __) :> Remove @@ Select[StringEndsQ[id]][
       List @@ 
        SymbolName /@ Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[f][[All, 1, 1]]
       ]
    ];
   ];
  Function[, marker; f[##], HoldAllComplete]
  ]

getMultiplier[n_] := addGCMarker@Module[{f, g},
  f[x_] := n*g[x];
  g[x_] := x + 2;
  f
  ]

M = getMultiplier[4]
(* Function[Null, marker$4088; f$4087[##1], HoldAllComplete] *)

M =.
(* Removed! *)

(*f$xxxx smf h$xxxx are indeed gone*)
Names["f*" | "g*"]
(* {"f", "f$", "g", "getMultiplier", "g$"} *)
```

An alternative is to wrap the `addGCMarker` call around the `Module`, and let it inspect the `Module`. As opposed to the other two variants, this one has to be applied directly to the `Module[...]` expression:

```
Attributes[addGCMarker2] = {HoldFirst};
addGCMarker2[Module[vars_, body_]] := Module[{marker},
  Module[vars,
   AddCleanupFunction[marker,
    Echo@"Removed!";
    Remove /@ vars;
    ];
   With[{f = body},
    Function[, marker; f[##], HoldAllComplete]
    ]
   ]
  ]

getMultiplier[n_] := addGCMarker2@Module[{f, g},
   f[x_] := n*g[x];
   g[x_] := x + 2;
   f
   ]

(* same behavior *)
```

### Original version

Here's the original version using subvalue definitions for `f`:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

<< ExpressionCleanup`

getMultiplier[n_] :=
  Module[{f, marker},
   f[_][x_] := n*x;
   AddCleanupFunction[marker, Echo@"Removed!"; Remove@f];
   f[marker]
   ];

M = getMultiplier[4]
(* f$4080[marker$4080] *)

M[4]
(* 16 *)

M =.
(* Removed! *)

(* f$4080 is indeed gone *)
Names["f*"]
(* {"f", "f$"} *)
```

Since we have full control over the symbol `marker`, it might be possible to get around the need for the paclet, but currently I don't see a way.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137165/discussion-on-answer-by-lukas-lang-garbage-collection-for-lexical-closures).

Comment: I have put an updated version of this function [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/JasonB/WeakCache/ref/CleanupAfter.html).  There are some other functions in that paclet which might be of general interest

Answer (score 11):

If you can afford this from performance standpoint, you can generate definitions at every function call:

```
ClearAll[getMultiplier]
getMultiplier[n_] := 
  Function[
    x, 
    Module[
      {f},
      Block[{f},
        f[xx_] := n * xx;
        f[x]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

This extends to functions with multiple definitions, including memoization. The combination of `Module` and `Block` ensures that all definitions for `f` are destroyed after the code exits `Block` (which guarantees that the generated symbol `f$nnn` gets GC-ed), while keeping the name of `f` unique.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I understand correctly, this allows one to give multiple definitions for `f` which can be used to implement, say, recursive functions and one can memoize values to try to keep the recursion short. On the downside, this approach generates a new symbol `f` for each function call, so there is no persistent state. But it is really that state, and memoization in that persistent sense, that make closures so useful (I am mostly thinking about applications where performance is an issue).

Comment: @user293787 You are correct. Regarding the persistent state, the function will have it during the function call. So memoization is still possible. You can see how it works e.g. [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39016/81). If you need to maintain the state in between several distinct function calls, in that case indeed my suggestion won't work for you. You may also be interested in my answer in [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85762/81), which describes a possible scheme to implement memoization for `Function` - based functions.

Comment: Yes, by persistent I mean over distinct function calls. Thank you for the links. [Your approach here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85762/85954) using an `Association`, to avoid `DownValues`, is a proper workaround. That approach has automatic memory management (garbage collection) at the cost of extra code to manage the `Association` and losing various conveniences of `DownValues`.

Comment: @user293787 Indeed, in that approach for `Function` - based memoization, one loses the convenience of `DownValues`. I have experimented with a different approach, based on [this package](https://github.com/jasondbiggs/ExpressionCleanup). I was able to achieve partial GC in this way, but there are cases when this still does not work. I could post what I have, if you are interested, but this is at best a partial solution.

Comment: This github repository looks very promising! If you feel like posting that github link as a separate answer, and briefly indicate how one can use it for memory management, then I'd be happy to accept that answer. No worries, it does not have to be perfect, I am just looking for new ideas and trying to improve my Mathematica skills.